# Kivy/MySQL/colab-google Mysql request does not work

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, google-colaboratory

I'm using python/Kivy/MySQL/colab-google to compile an apk. When I run the app on Android, I give the command to register the app shuts down.

main.py

```
  import kivy
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
  from kivy.lang import Builder
  from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
  import mysql.connector

  Builder.load_file("main.kv")
 class registerScreen(Screen):
     usernameInput = ObjectProperty(None)
     emailInput = ObjectProperty(None)
     passwordInput = ObjectProperty(None)
def addInfoToDB(self):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        db="tornikesch",
        host="localhost",
        user="tttt",
        password="1111")
    values = (self.usernameInput.text, self.emailInput.text, self.passwordInput.text)
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    query = "INSERT INTO registeredusers (Username, Email, Password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    db.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
class loginScreen(Screen):
    usernameInputLogin = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwordInputLogin = ObjectProperty(None)
    def checkIfDetailsExist(self):
       db = mysql.connector.connect(
           db="torn",
           host="localhost",
           user="tttt",
           password="1111")
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM registeredusers")
    fetchInfo = cursor.fetchone()
    if self.usernameInputLogin.text in fetchInfo and self.passwordInputLogin.text in 
fetchInfo:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")
class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(loginScreen(name='login'))
    sm.add_widget(registerScreen(name='register'))
    return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The reason I suggest is a call to mysql.
What is the solution when using kivy to call mysql.
Please help me..

Comment: using `host="localhost"` on Android it tries to connect to MySQL installed on Android. Do you have server `MySQL` on Android ? As I know there is no MySQL for Android. If you want to connect with database on other computer then you have to use `host="Other_Computer_Address_IP"` - and server has to accept connections on IP `0.0.0.0`, not `localhost`.

Comment: I changed it and it worked, but only when I am on the wifi, when I connect the mobile internet does not load, need I to add a port (3306)?

Comment: when you connect from internet then it may need change settings in your `router` (hardware which gives access to internet) - set `port forwarding`. But sometimes it may not work because between your computer and computer/phone in internet there can be also `router` in building of you `Internet Provider` and you can't change settings in this `router`. Sometimes it is simpler to run code on servers on internet which always have access. Eventually you may try to use ports like 80, 8080, 443 which normally are used for WWW servers and `Internet Provider` may have `port forwarding` for these ports.